# UITableview Cell scrolling time textfield data is disappearing after update text

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am using UITableview cell for listing a set of questions and 2 textfield is for score 1 and score 2 i inputed the score and total showed on a label after that when am scrolling time the inputed data is disappear on the UITableview .Some one please help me to solve this issue and am adding these textfield and label on the view and this view is the subview of cell.contentview

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else{
    for (UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

text field added as

```
UIView * vwbackground = [[UIView alloc] init];
[vwbackground setFrame: CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-10, 90)];
vwbackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:vwbackground];

self.txtfldInPut1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
self.txtfldInPut1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.txtfldInPut1.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
[vwbackground addSubview:self.txtfldInPut1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because data in table cell is keep on changing as per list items when scrolls . This is a feature of cells in table view . 
what you need to do is at the time when put enter your score just update that value to the array/dictonary(whatever you have taken) from which you are intially showing your data in the list.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Am taking that data to one string and i set one bool if reloading put that data that time also the data is disappearing

Comment: just for clarification is the main data is coming from api i.e is it in jason format

Comment: yes the main data coming from the api and user adding the score 1 and 2 and sum also showing after scrolled it is disappearing

Comment: do these things as far as i undestand your question .. 
1).save that data coming from api for the very first time to your local dict. 
2). show the list in listview from the local dictonary you have taken 
3) . as user enter score then update the dict with the scores . 
if you do these then data comes in updated scores as you wanted even after scroll up.

Comment: just for ex. 
{
    "input": [
        {
            "question": "any1",
            "scores": "0"
     },
        {
            "question": "any2",
            "scores": "0"
        },
        {
           "question": "any3",
            "scores": "0"
        }
    ]
}
your local dict should look like this and update score as per score entered

Comment: no only questions and id get from the server and using this id and inputed score we went to pass to server that i done only thing is after input tableview scrolling time the text disappear